# Implicit type conversion for lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, type-conversion, java-8, overloading

Consider the following piece of class:

```
public void method() {
    test(() -> { });
}

void test(Runnable a) {
    System.out.println("Test 1");
}

void test(A a) {
    System.out.println("Test 2");
}

interface A extends Runnable {

}
```

Invoking method `method()` will lead to `Test 2` output. This means, that lambda expression `() -> { }` was implicitly converted to `A`. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same standard rule applied to all overloads. [Java will choose the most specific applicable method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

Both methods accept an argument that is of a functional interface type. The lambda expression

```
() -> { }
```

is convertible to both those types. `A` is a subclass of `Runnable` and is therefore more specific. The method with a parameter type of `A` therefore gets chosen.